# Multiple large requests using aiohttp

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need to send a large number (approximately 50) of HTTP POST requests, each with a size of around 5 MB. I use the asyncio.gather function to wait for the responses from these requests. However, the [JSON serialization process](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L383) takes approximately 30-40 milliseconds and blocks the EventLoop.

This causes all requests to be sent to the server simultaneously. For instance, if there are 50 requests and the first request is available at time T, it is only sent at (T + (50 * 30) = T + 1500ms). Additionally, at T+1500 ms, all 50 requests are sent to the server. I want Aiohttp to send requests as soon as they become available.

Can I bypass the JSON serialization step to achieve this?

Also, [this line](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py#L1106) is where aiohttp is waiting for the eventloop. Our APIs are latency sensitive. Is there any way to speed up this? or any other alternatives?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: perhaps the fact that the line you want to bypass is in an `if` condition gives you a hint about what you need to do ?

Comment: Could you let us know what you are trying to achieve? For example if you need to send a large number of POST requests, could you send them using a queue? I wonder if you have an X-Y problem here.

Comment: "if . . . the first request is available at time T, it is only sent at (T + (50 * 30) = T + 1500ms)".  This seems to imply that you are serializing requests that are not available.  That doesn't make any sense.  If you want to send requests as soon as they are available, why are the "unavailable" requests stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I can't optimize code I can't see.

Comment: "This seems to imply that you are serializing requests that are not available."
No, it means that 50 requests have been queued up in individual tasks (explained when `asyncio.gather()` was mentioned). The event loop will then run 1 iteration of each task, each of which calls `json.dumps()`. Thus, 1.5 seconds delay before the first task gets to run the second part of their task and actually send the payload.

The question was phrased fine _if_ you have good familiarity with aiohttp or asyncio. The comments here seem to have missed the intricacies of asyncio programming.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the `json` convenience parameter to send the JSON response. For such a large request, and if performance is critical, it sounds like you'd be better encoding it beforehand.

e.g. Something like:

```
def prepare_data(obj) -> bytes:
    return json.dumps(obj).encode()

data = await asyncio.to_thread(prepare_data, obj)
async with sess.post(data=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}) as resp:
```

Just be careful that `obj` can't be modified during this time (something that is immutable would be preferable).

> Also, this line is where aiohttp is waiting for the eventloop. Our APIs are latency sensitive. Is there any way to speed up this? or any other alternatives?

If you install `aiohttp[speedups]` that will include aiodns, which should speed up DNS resolutions. Or, you could pass an IP address to skip DNS resolution completely.

(Also, make sure you're reusing the session, otherwise you'd be throwing away the DNS cache each time).

Answer (score 0):

Today I was reviewing a repository which is released recently named Asyncer (which is on top of Anyio) introduced by Sebastian Ramirez the creator of the FastAPI. In the documentation, the part that absorbed me was related to the "**call a sync code from an async code**" which I think is the same issue you have — blocking code (i.e. JSON serialization) inside an async code.

At the same time, I recalled this question to propose a contemporary solution for it!

Therefore, using Asyncer's `asyncify`, you would wrap the JSON serialization process into a function and then use `asyncify` to create an asynchronous version of that function. Besides that, you could adopt Asyncer's `task_group()` feature as well, which also exists on python 3.11 asyncio. Here's how you could do it:

```py
import anyio
import aiohttp
import json
import time

from asyncer import asyncify, create_task_group

def serialize_json(data):
    # Simulate a blocking operation
    time.sleep(0.03)
    return json.dumps(data)

async def send_post_request(session, url, data):
    serialized_data = await asyncify(serialize_json)(data=data)  # Note
    response = await session.post(url, data=serialized_data)
    return response

async def main():
    url = "http://python.org"
    data_to_send = [{"data": "your_data_here"}] * 50

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with create_task_group() as tg:
            for data in data_to_send:
                tg.soonify(send_post_request)(session=session, url=url, data=data)
        ...  # Rest of your code

anyio.run(main)  # or asyncio.run(main()) or asyncer.runnify(main)()
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- Asyncer's `asyncify` [docs](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/asyncify/).
- Asyncer's `task_group` [docs](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/soonify/).